# SELECT INTO or Stored Procedure?

Tags: php, stored-procedures, mysql

Would this be better as a stored procedure or leave it as is?

```
INSERT INTO `user_permissions` 
    ( `user_id`, `object_id`, `type`, `view`, `add`, `edit`, `delete`, `admin`, `updated_by_user_id` ) 
    SELECT `user_id`, $object_id, '$type', 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, $user_id 
    FROM `user_permissions` 
    WHERE `object_id` = $object_id_2 AND `type` = '$type_2' AND `admin` = 1
```

You can think of this with different objects, lets say you have groups and subgroups. If someone creates a subgroup, it is making everyone who had access to the parent group now also have access to the subgroup.

I've never made a stored procedure before, but this looks like it might be time. This call be probably be called very often.

Should I be creating a procedure or will the performance be insignificant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Wikipedia [Stored Procedure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_procedure):

> **Overhead**: Because stored procedure
>   statements are stored directly in the
>   database, this may remove all or part
>   of the compilation overhead that is
>   typically required in situations where
>   software applications send inline
>   (dynamic) SQL queries to a database.
>   (However, most database systems
>   implement "statement caches" and other
>   mechanisms to avoid repetitive
>   compilation of dynamic SQL
>   statements.) In addition, pre-compiled
>   SQL statements, while avoiding some
>   overhead, add to the complexity of
>   creating an optimal execution plan
>   because not all arguments of the SQL
>   statement are supplied at compile
>   time. Depending on the specific
>   database implementation and
>   configuration, mixed performance
>   results will be seen from stored
>   procedures versus generic queries or
>   user defined functions.
>
> **Avoidance of network traffic**: A major
>   advantage with stored procedures is
>   that they can run directly within the
>   database engine. In a production
>   system, this typically means that the
>   procedures run entirely on a
>   specialized database server, which has
>   direct access to the data being
>   accessed. The benefit here is that
>   network communication costs can be
>   avoided completely. This becomes
>   particularly important for complex
>   series of SQL statements.
>
> **Encapsulation of business logic**:
>   Stored procedures allow for business
>   logic to be embedded as an API in the
>   database, which can simplify data
>   management and reduce the need to
>   encode the logic elsewhere in client
>   programs. This may result in a lesser
>   likelihood of data becoming corrupted
>   through the use of faulty client
>   programs. Thus, the database system
>   can ensure data integrity and
>   consistency with the help of stored
>   procedures.
>
> **Delegation of access-rights**: In many
>   systems, stored-procedures can be
>   granted access rights to the database
>   which the users who will execute those
>   procedures do not directly have. Thus,
>   the stored procedure becomes the only
>   way that these users have, to do
>   whatever the stored procedure does.
>
> **Some protection from SQL injection
>   attacks**: Stored procedures can be used
>   to protect against this attack. The
>   parameters will be treated as data
>   even if an attacker inserts SQL
>   commands. Also some DBMS will check
>   the parameter's type.
>
> **Disadvantages**
>
> Stored procedures are "defined once,
>   used many times." If any changes are
>   necessary, the (one and only one)
>   definition of the stored procedure
>   must be replaced. Dynamic SQL, of
>   course, allows any SQL query to be
>   issued at any time. Any change to a
>   stored procedure instantly impacts
>   every other piece of software, report,
>   etc. (inside or outside of the DBMS)
>   which directly or indirectly refers to
>   it. It is not always possible to
>   determine with certainty exactly what
>   those impacts will be, nor what
>   changes can safely be made without
>   adversely impacting something else.
>
> For various reasons, many
>   organizations strictly limit who is
>   allowed to define and issue a query
>   against the database. Programmers and
>   other users may therefore find
>   themselves having no choice but to
>   implement inefficient solutions to
>   their problems using what stored
>   procedures are available to them,
>   whether or not the procedures are
>   appropriate for this particular
>   ancillary task.
>
> Though not directly related to stored
>   procedures, the movement of business
>   logic to the DBMS is problematic since
>   it is the layer with the more complex
>   scalability issues. Furthermore, some
>   modern DBMS systems (notably from
>   Microsoft SQL Server 2000 onwards)
>   don't offer any performance benefits
>   of using stored procedures against
>   precompiled queries: they are compiled
>   and cached in the same manner as
>   dynamic SQL.

So, in your example, you want the encapsulation benefits of a Stored Procedure, and should probably *just do it*.